# Verilog compile error: Unidentified variable 2'b00

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to create a simple 32-bit ALU.

```
module alu (a, b, f, y, zero);
input [31:0] a, b;
input [2:0] f;
output [31:0] y;
output zero;

reg [31:0] bb, s; 
always @ (*) begin

    assign bb = (f[2] == 0) ? b : (~b);

    case( f[1:0] )
        2’b00 : y = (a & bb);
        2’b01 : y = (a | bb);
        2’b10 : y = (a + bb + f[2] );
        2’b11 : begin
                s = (a + bb + f[2] );
                y[0] = (s[31]);
                y[31:1] = 31’b0; 
            end
    endcase
end

zero = ((y == 32’b0) ? 1 : 0); //if y is 000..0000, set to 1

endmodule
```

There are 4 errors I get when I run it in ModelSim:

1. In Line 15, "Unidentified variable b00"
2. In Line 15, "near '=': syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ++ or --
3. In Line 21, "Unidentified variable b0"
4. In Line 21, "near ';': syntax error, unexpected ';'

I've spent a long time trying to figure out what these errors are referring to, especially the "unidentified variable" ones. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `y` as `reg` since you make a procedural assignment to it (in an `always` block).

You need to move the `assign` statement out of the `always` block.

You need to use the `assign` keyword for `zero` since it is a continuous assignment.

You need to replace those strange single-quote characters (`2’b00`) with ASCII single quotes (`2'b00`) everywhere.

```
module alu (a, b, f, y, zero);
input [31:0] a, b;
input [2:0] f;
output reg [31:0] y;
output zero;

reg [31:0] bb, s; 

assign bb = (f[2] == 0) ? b : (~b);
  
always @ (*) begin
    case( f[1:0] )
        2'b00 : y = (a & bb);
        2'b01 : y = (a | bb);
        2'b10 : y = (a + bb + f[2] );
        2'b11 : begin
                s = (a + bb + f[2] );
                y[0] = (s[31]);
                y[31:1] = 31'b0; 
            end
    endcase
end

assign  zero = ((y == 32'b0) ? 1 : 0); //if y is 000..0000, set to 1

endmodule
```

This code compiles without errors on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6uZE).